# Slow Performance with dask as size of dataframe increases

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I've got a somewhat intensive function (called myfunction) that I've been using to create a new column in a pandas dataframe using pandas apply.  Rather than getting into the details of the `myfunction` function, the pseudocode for it is as such...

```
def myfunction(row):
        temporary_df = a_different_df.copy()                                
        temporary_df = temporary_df[some_custom_slice which depends on row column values]
        temporary_df['var1'] = vectorized_function(temporary_df[somecolumn], row['var'])
        temporary_df['var2'] = another_vectorized_function(temporary_df[somecolumn2], row['var2'])
        return temporary_df['var1'].sum() + temporary_df['var2'].mean()
```

Now, this calculation takes some time and I thought that I might be able to speed this up by using Dask, since the pandas apply is independent for each passed in row from `pandas_df`...

`result = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df,npartitions = cpu_count()).map_partitions(lambda y : y.apply(myfunction, axis=1, result_type='expand')).compute(scheduler='processes')`

For smaller dataframes, this works great and I get a decent speed up.  However, as the size of `pandas_df` increases, I've found that the time to complete the calculation doesn't increase linearly.

Now, this might be a little bit convoluted to explain, but `a_different_df` is actually a paired down version of the `pandas_df` on which the apply function is occurring within map partitions.  The reason why I found this to be necessary was that the calculations in `myfunction` depend only on the current row but also on the historical data prior to that row.

Amount of time series data in pandas_dataframe...

```
1 month of data : 1 minute compute time
3 months of data : 4.5 minute compute time
6 months of data : 14 minute compute time
12 months of data : 46 minute compute time
5 years of data : ?? (Dask Progress Bar at 0% after 45 minutes...)
```

Initially I thought that this was due to having too few partitions, and therefore overloading memory as the size of the dataframes increased.  However, I didn't seen any increase in speed with 1 year of data when increasing the partitions from 8 to 96.  I was thinking that since this is just delayed computation, it should scale linearly with the size of the dataframe.

My question is, am I thinking about this wrong (in terms of linear scaling), and is there a more suitable approach to scaling this computation to a larger dataframe with dask?  The only alternative I can see right now is to execute the computation on 1 month of data at a time, and then concatenate the dataframe in the end which seems unnecessary...

Comment: Can you improve your pseudocode to show how you are using `row`? Why do you need to make a copy of the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, that's ngoing to be incredibly slow... you are making a copy of the entire data frame for each row???

Comment: Yeah.  I can't think of a better way to simultaneously act on the current row while requiring a slice of the entire dataframe which is not constant in time (the slice required has to be calculated based on the row criterion... I will add that into the question...)

Comment: Now I feel rather silly... and see what you mean.  By not making a full copy but just slicing the portion of the dataframe that I need that fully eliminates the issue.